# pyspark chunking data causes memory constraint

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a requirement to chunk a large dataset with a few million rows, so that an API call can be made for every 10k rows.

I came up with something like:

```
dataframe_refs = []

    total_splits = math.ceil(dataframe.count() / subset_length)
    step = 0
    while step < total_splits:
        temp_df = dataframe.limit(subset_length)
        dataframe = dataframe.subtract(temp_df)
        dataframe_refs.append(temp_df)
        step += 1
```

in order to chunk the data into smaller DataFrame references, that I then would call collect on. `for each_chunk in dataframe_refs: ...`

But the loop seems to run and get slower each passing. Does `LIMIT` or `SUBTRACT` cause the initial DataFrame to start performing operations instead of being lazy loaded?